# Why does this throw a NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, linq-to-xml, nullreferenceexception

```
private void alterNodeValue(string xmlFile, string parent, string node, string newVal)
{
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(this.dir + xmlFile);

    if (xml.Element(parent).Element(node).Value != null)
    {
        xml.Element(parent).Element(node).Value = newVal;
    }
    else
    {
        xml.Element(parent).Add(new XElement(node, newVal)); 
    }

    xml.Save(dir + xmlFile); 
}
```

Why does this throw

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

on this line

```
if (xml.Element(parent).Element(node).Value != null)
```

?

I'm guessing it's because the XML node doesn't exist, but that's what the `!= null` is suppose to check for. How do I fix that?

I've tried several things and they ALL throw the same exception at some point during the not null check.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either `xml.Element(parent)` or the `Element(node)` you are trying to access from the return value of `xml.Element(parent)` is `null`.

Restructuring like this will enable to you see which one it is:

```
var myElement = xml.Element(parent);
if (xmyElement != null)
{
    var myNode = myElement.Element(node);
    if(myNode != null)
    {
      myNode.Value = newVal;
    }
}
```

---

Update:

From your comment it looks like you want to do this:

```
if (xml.Element(parent).Element(node) != null)  // <--- No .Value
{
    xml.Element(parent).Element(node).Value = newVal;
}
else
{
    xml.Element(parent).Add(new XElement(node, newVal)); 
}
```

Comment: parent exists, node doesn't. I'm trying to catch `Element(node) == null` and add it through the `else` statement.

Comment: @PiZzL3 - If you know it doesn't exist, why are you doing a `.Value` on the _non existent_ node?

Comment: I'm still learning how to use `XDocument` properly. I don't know all the details.

Comment: @PiZzL3 - If the node doesn't exist, it will be a `null` object. Any call on that would result in the exception.

Comment: Ahh k, thanks for the help! I thought calling `.Value` would grab the `null` so I could compare it.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost certainly because this returns null:

```
xml.Element(parent)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if:

```
Element(node) != null
```

Before you call .Value. If Element(node) == null, then the call to .Value will throw a null reference exception.

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your if statement to this:

```
if (xml.Element(parent).Element(node) != null)
```

If the node in the parent element is null, you cannot access a member of a null object.

Answer (score 1):

At least:

```
private void alterNodeValue(string xmlFile, string parent, string node, string newVal)
{
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(this.dir + xmlFile);
    XElement parent = xml.Element(parent).Element(node);
    if (parent  != null)
    {
        parent.Value = newVal;
    }
    else
    {
        xml.Element(parent).Add(new XElement(node, newVal)); 
    }    
    xml.Save(dir + xmlFile); 
}
```

Better:

```
private void alterNodeValue(string xmlFile, string parent, string node, string newVal)
{
    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, xmlFile);
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(path );
    XElement parent = xml.Element(parent).Element(node);
    if (parent != null)
    {
        XElement node = parent.Element(parent);
        if (node != null)
        {
            node.Value = newVal;
        }
        else
        {
            // no node
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // no parent
    }    
    xml.Save(path); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (xml.Element(parent) != null)
        {
            var myNode = xml.Element(parent).Element(node);
            if (node != null)
                myNode.Value = newVal;
        }
        else
        {
            xml.Element(parent).Add(new XElement(node, newVal));
        }
```